# Timezones in Google Mail Markup

Tags: google-schemas

We recently implemented the Rental car Mail Markup. For this we implemented the pickup and dropoff time as ISO dates as shown in the documentation. Nevertheless it appeared to us that the timezones of our dates has been ignored and thus we removed the timezone and add the date in local time of the pickup destination. Now we still get reports that in some occasions our date is interpreted as being UTC+0 and then displayed with a wrong time. What is the right way to put in the date so that it will be correctly displayed in google mail?
Thanks in advance

Our Mail includes this snippet

```
{
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "RentalCarReservation",
    "reservationNumber": "K0523X3368",
    "reservationStatus": "http://schema.org/Pending",
    "url": "...",
    "underName": {
        "@type": "Person",
        "name": "....",
        "email": "..."
    },
    "programMembership": {
        "@type": "ProgramMembership",
        "memberNumber": ...,
        "program": "..."
    },
    "bookingAgent": {
        "@type": "Organization",
        "name": "...",
        "url": "..."
    },
    "reservationFor": {
        "@type": "RentalCar",
        "name": "FIAT PANDA",
        "model": "MBMR",
        "brand": {
            "@type": "Brand",
            "name": "FIAT PANDA"
        },
        "description": "FIAT PANDA",
        "rentalCompany": {
            "@type": "Organization",
            "name": "Hiper Rentacar"
        }
    },
    "pickupLocation": {
        "@type": "Place",
        "name": "Palma de Mallorca Airport",
        "address": {
            "@type": "PostalAddress",
            "streetAddress": "Palma de Mallorca Airport",
            "addressLocality": "Palma",
            "postalCode": "07611",
            "addressRegion": "ES",
            "addressCountry": "ES"
        }
    },
    "pickupTime": "2019-02-13T14:00:00.000+00:00",
    "dropoffLocation": {
        "@type": "Place",
        "name": "Palma de Mallorca Airport",
        "address": {
            "@type": "PostalAddress",
            "streetAddress": "Palma de Mallorca Airport",
            "addressLocality": "Palma",
            "postalCode": "07611",
            "addressRegion": "ES",
            "addressCountry": "ES"
        }
    },
    "dropoffTime": "2019-02-14T08:00:00.000+00:00",
    "cancelReservationUrl": "...",
    "modifyReservationUrl": "...",
    "potentialAction": [
        {
            "@type": "EditAction",
            "target": "..."
        }
    ],
    "price": 16.91,
    "priceCurrency": "EUR",
    "modifiedTime": "2018-05-23T09:20:32.861Z"
}
```

the resulting card looks like that
[mail card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9ESB.png)

All dates are shown in UTC although my machine is currently located in Germany and the rentlocation is in Spain (both CEST)

Comment: Can you show the relevant codes on how you did your UTC settings? This [guide might help](https://searchenginewatch.com/2016/08/03/how-to-add-schema-org-markup-to-your-email-marketing/): 'You might be wondering about the time-stamp on the start date, “2016-08-30T08:00:00-08:00.” As far as I can tell, when writing start times for an event using Microdata formatting, you have to specify the timezone in UTC. So because our event is in San Francisco, UTC-8, our 8am start time is written as 08:00:00-08:00'

Comment: Thanks for the answer i updated the question and attached an example